# What effect do the double @ signs have in a FAKE build script?

Tags: f#-fake

I'm currently exploring FAKE, a build system for .NET based on F#. Now I come across a strange operator: a double at sign ("@@"). What does this operator do? I could not find any reference to it in the documentation. Here is an example:

```
let net45Dir = packagingDir @@ "lib/net45/"
```

I would guess that it is able to combine two path strings in a reliable way. Meaning that the combined path string has one and only one slash between the parts.

Comment: This is a smiley. Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it in the documentation:

https://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-environmenthelper.html

> ( @@ ) path1 path2
>
> Signature: path1:string -> path2:string -> string
>
> Combines two path strings using Path.Combine

Nice feature!